# Subsets or Outer?

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

How do I generate all possible subsets of a list of positive numbers (with at least 1 of them), given that each of these positive numbers subvariates itself on its input value and its multiplicative inverse?

Example:

```
{2,3}
```

Capability expected:

```
{{2},{1/2},{3},{1/3},{2,3},{1/2,3},{2,1/3},{1/2,1/3}}
```

Comment: Do you want the empty set in the final list?

Comment: @Virgil, preferably not. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
f[list_] := Join @@ (Tuples[ Transpose[{#, 1/#}] ] & /@ Subsets[list, {1, ∞}])


f[{2,3,4}]
```

> {{2}, {1/2}, {3}, {1/3}, {4}, {1/4}, {2, 3}, {2, 1/3}, {1/2, 3}, {1/2,
>      1/3}, {2, 4}, {2, 1/4}, {1/2, 4}, {1/2, 1/4}, {3, 4}, {3, 1/4}, {1/
>     3, 4}, {1/3, 1/4}, {2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 1/4}, {2, 1/3, 4}, {2, 1/3, 1/
>     4}, {1/2, 3, 4}, {1/2, 3, 1/4}, {1/2, 1/3, 4}, {1/2, 1/3, 1/4}}

I don't know if you want to take a special care of 1 and 0.

Comment: A very nice solution.

Comment: @kuba, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

A couple of ideas come to mind. Here's one approach - get all subsets of a list of equal length in symbolic form, then iterate each symbol over the member of the list and its inverse.

```
list = {2, 3};
Flatten[
 Table[
  Evaluate@Subsets[Array[f, Length[list]], {1, Infinity}],
  Evaluate@
    (Sequence @@ Array[{f[#], {list[[#]]^-1, list[[#]]}} &, Length[list]])], Length[list]]
```

This unfortunately requires `DeleteDuplicates` afterwards, as it works as follows:

Make a list `{{a}, {b}, {a, b}}`, iterate with `{a, {1/2, 2}}, {b, {1/3, 3}}`, which naturally results in duplicates.

Another approach:

```
variate[l_] := (Power[l, #] & /@ Tuples[{-1, 1}, Length[l]])
Sequence @@ variate[#] & /@ Subsets[list, {1, Infinity}]
```

> `{{1/2}, {2}, {1/3}, {3}, {1/2, 1/3}, {1/2, 3}, {2, 1/3}, {2, 3}}`

Two lines, but much more readable. Avoids iterators. Doesn't result in duplicates, like with the first approach.

The second approach works as follows:

Take all subsets of the list with length 1 or greater.
Apply to each of the subsets the auxiliary `variate` function.
The `variate` function works like this: check the length of the subset being processed and generate all `Tuples` of `{-1, 1}` of this length. Raise the subset to the power of each of the tuples.

Say for example, we are looking at the subset `{2, 3}`. In *Mathematica* the `Power` function is `Listable`, so `{2, 3}^{-1, 1} == {1/2, 3}`. And `Tuples[{-1, 1}, 2]` gives us all combinations describing "take the first element, and inverse of second element, take inverse of first and second, take inverse of both, just take both" by returning `{-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}`. The `{2, 3}` is raised to each of these powers.

Comment: @lliamnyp, the single-element subsets are repeated and I'm unable to understand why.

Comment: @Samuel I see why. Use my second approach, it should be much more efficient. I'll try and see if I can refine the first method, short of just throwing in `DeleteDuplicates` around it, but it's really just for fun now.

Comment: @lliamnyp, thank you very much!
Could you summarize the rationale of the second approach?